# How to create predictions using smoothing splines in r?

Tags: r, predict, smoothing, spline

I fitted a smoothing spline model in r. To my understanding, r selects the optimal number of knots for my predictor x by default, right? In the end, what I really want is to predict y in the training set and test set.

I ran the following code to create my model:

```
fit_training <- smooth.spline(training_dataset$x, training_dataset$y)
```

Then, I tried to predict y in my training set and consequently tried to calculate the training MSE. Unfortunately, I get an error when running the following code:

```
#training MSE from the smoothing spline model
yhat_training <- predict(fit_training, newx = X_training_set)
mean((yhat_training - y_training_set)^2)
```

The error reads: "
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': non-numerical argument for binary operator".
What does this mean exactly?

Thank you in advance for your support.

```
dput(training_dataset[1:200, c(1, 74)])
structure(list(y = c(6.205274, 6.252587, 
6.723128, 5.909961, 7.56648, 5.537569, 5.555622, 5.600009, 4.993981, 
4.703318, 5.622036, 6.546198, 5.521432, 4.841585, 6.536844, 6.099358, 
6.530076, 6.313496, 5.986368, 5.984339, 6.382049, 6.738477, 5.567231, 
5.21584, 6.630187, 5.460565, 6.285039, 4.529988, 6.609529, 6.435844, 
6.027709, 6.41529, 7.134712, 6.121739, 4.534837, 6.750215, 5.81161, 
5.862023, 5.968873, 6.056121, 6.11675, 6.785589, 6.302466, 5.298549, 
5.753188, 6.353673, 5.18986, 6.406951, 5.382667, 6.006859, 6.277811, 
6.263347, 6.412899, 6.010227, 5.299894, 4.91048, 5.981753, 4.997011, 
5.823404, 6.448229, 4.473924, 5.342726, 6.279317, 5.24948, 5.686925, 
6.357457, 4.94221, 4.850336, 5.900735, 6.428448, 5.760784, 6.546414, 
4.846154, 6.251719, 5.809406, 6.302069, 5.486672, 6.347095, 5.568854, 
5.703978, 5.60134, 7.04655, 6.965587, 4.942137, 6.177781, 5.990265, 
5.449095, 7.162749, 5.665896, 5.201321, 4.704261, 6.198475, 6.041397, 
5.960272, 7.255023, 6.893871, 6.320576, 4.505745, 6.205615, 3.75926, 
5.097384, 6.199368, 5.184588, 6.446023, 5.843382, 5.080692, 6.210401, 
5.52641, 4.138352, 5.075018, 5.371879, 7.122709, 6.837977, 7.216923, 
6.318508, 5.597323, 6.265491, 5.961889, 4.938662, 5.009977, 4.451892, 
6.25833, 7.29302, 5.774138, 6.219595, 5.224521, 5.529301, 6.020412, 
6.738822, 5.683955, 5.726123, 6.232398, 5.232553, 7.03011, 6.401871, 
5.862978, 5.97432, 6.092692, 5.718245, 5.753114, 5.485445, 5.733912, 
5.90101, 6.797256, 5.741323, 6.863926, 6.73023, 6.463243, 3.906936, 
4.769026, 6.492951, 4.093934, 5.545223, 5.617377, 6.630804, 5.875215, 
6.090399, 5.001747, 6.609125, 4.844843, 5.476038, 6.001385, 5.282911, 
6.17313, 6.185719, 5.980755, 5.652625, 4.447541, 4.824138, 5.875164, 
6.680261, 5.809895, 5.622861, 5.756104, 5.569914, 6.325106, 5.4566, 
5.705943, 6.338689, 5.945594, 5.022046, 7.534237, 6.680004, 5.197282, 
7.254047, 6.229307, 6.25997, 6.067185, 5.778612, 5.674632, 4.902741, 
6.982681, 4.75993, 5.10193, 5.259747, 4.972389, 6.202915, 5.977957, 
6.868953, 5.344525), x = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please include some simulated or real data so that we're able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you for your feedback and sorry for not putting any data to my original posting. I've edited it.

Comment: You did not define `y_training_set` and you provided whole data frames to `mean()` instead of vectors. Try `mean((yhat_training$x - training_dataset$y)^2)`.